# ¿Por qué las instancias que creo no reciben correctamente las clases CSS que definí?

Tags: javascript-objeto, constructor

Estoy tratando de crear un juego de memorama principalmente usando JavaScript y CSS. En mi script tengo una serie de arrays que contienen emojis por pares. Esos arrays los concateno en uno solo, después revuelvo el contenido del nuevo array para dividirlo y repartir las cartas por filas en el div `container` mediante la función `dealCards()`, donde se crean las instancias de la clase `Card` y los elementos HTML correspondientes.

Al ejecutarlo con LiveServer las instancias `Card` que se crean en mi `forEach()` no reciben correctamente las clases CSS que definí, que son necesarias para asegurar el correcto funcionamiento del juego, y creo que se debe a algún error en mi constructor y/o en la manera en la que estoy asignando las clases.

En mi CSS, la clase `card` define el dorso de la carta, mientras que `card-content`, el derecho, donde se ve el emoji o la imagen a la que se le busca par. La clase `flipped` se añade y remueve del objeto `Card` haciendo que la carta muestre el contenido o el dorso condicionalmente.

Aquí abajo dejo el código como referencia:

```js
class Card {
  constructor(cardEmoji) {
    const cardElement = document.createElement("div");
    cardElement.classList.add("card");
    const cardContent = document.createElement("div");
    cardContent.classList.add("cardContent");
    cardContent.innerHTML = cardEmoji;
    cardElement.appendChild(cardContent);
    //With the cardElement built locally, assign it to another variable to
    //access it from outside the constructor
    this.cardElement = cardElement;
    this.cardElement.flipped = false;
    //The line below, clears contexts: the "this" clause in the params is the
    //function call, and the "this.flipCards" references the object's function
    this.flipCards = this.flipCards.bind(this);
    this.cardElement.addEventListener("click", this.flipCards);
  }
  flipCards() {
    const flippedCards = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      if (!this.flipped) {
        this.classList.add("flipped");
        this.flipped = true;
      }
      //Stores the selected cards shortly
      flippedCards.push(this);

      if (flippedCards.length === 2) {
        //Compares the content of the cards and flip them back if it's different
        if (flippedCards[0].innerHTML !== flippedCards[1].innerHTML) {
          flippedCards.forEach(card => {
            card.classList.remove("flipped");
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function dealCards() {
  let cardGroup1 = ["‍", "‍", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  let cardGroup2 = ["", "", "✅", "✅", "", "", "", ""];
  let cardGroup3 = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  let cardGroup4 = ["", "", "", "", "✏️", "✏️", "⭐", "⭐"];
  const allCards = cardGroup1.concat(cardGroup2, cardGroup3, cardGroup4);

  //Shuffles cards and creates new arrays with them:
  const shuffledCards = allCards.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  const cardGroups = [
    shuffledCards.slice(0, 8),
    shuffledCards.slice(8, 16),
    shuffledCards.slice(16, 24),
    shuffledCards.slice(24, 32)
  ];

  //Declares the HTML element that will contain the cards generated:
  const container = document.getElementById("container");

  cardGroups.forEach(cardGroup => {
    cardGroup.forEach(cardEmoji => {
      //Creates a new Card instance
      const newCard = new Card(cardEmoji);
      //Adds the HTML component of the Card object to the div container
      container.appendChild(newCard.cardElement);
    })
  })
}
dealCards();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px 1px #0000001a;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #e90e33, #352258);
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-content {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding: 10%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px 1px #0000001a;
}

.card-content::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: Hola Regina, por un lado decir que un error que tenes es que estas haciendo `this.classList.add("flipped");` y debería ser `this.cardElement.classList.add("flipped");` y por otro señalar que no sería correcto que un `Card` maneje "todos" los `Card`. Deberías tener otra clase `Cards` (_notese las `s`_) que instancie todos los `Card`, los almancené y controle el funcionamiento del "tablero"

Comment: ¡Graciaaas! No me había dado cuenta de que estaba queriendo asignar una clase CSS directamente a un objeto, y no al elemento HTML que contiene ese objeto. @Marcos

Answer (score 1):

Al final resolví el problema específico con las clases, pero aparte de eso hubo que hacer modificaciones mayores al código en general para que funcionara como quería.

El problema de asignación radicaba en el código dentro del constructor, pues de entrada **confundí el nombre de mi clase `card-content` con el de la variable `cardContent`** en la parte donde tocaba crear el "sándwich" de elementos HTML => div card> div card-content> emoji:

```js
const cardContent = document.createElement("div");
cardContent.classList.add("cardContent");
cardContent.innerHTML = cardEmoji;
```

Además, aún después de corregir ese detalle, el "reflejo" de mi *sándwich HTML*, el *sándwich-objeto* de JavaScript, también estaba mal porque:

1. No estaba creándolo conforme a la estructura jerárquica que presenta el *sándwich HTML* como debe ser, con sus respectivas propiedades y, en este caso, *subpropiedades*
2. No estaba *metiendo* mi *sándwich HTML* "dentro" de mi *sándwich-objeto* JS para que este pudiera guardar los elementos y acceder a ellos como propiedades.

Dicho esto, me gustaría compartir el constructor completo actualizado para mostrar cuál fue la solución, solo en caso de que mis analogías sandwicheras no hubieran sido suficiente para ilustrar la solución al problema (xd):

```js
class Card {
  constructor(cardEmoji, flippedCards) {
    const cardElement = document.createElement("div");
    cardElement.classList.add("card");

    const cardContent = document.createElement("div");
    cardContent.classList.add("card-content");
    cardContent.innerHTML = cardEmoji;

    cardElement.appendChild(cardContent);
    cardElement.flipped = false;

    //Establishes that the cardContent div is a property under the same name
    //within cardElement
    cardElement.cardContent = cardContent;

    this.cardElement = cardElement;
    this.flipCards = this.flipCards.bind(this);
    this.cardElement.addEventListener("click", () => this.flipCards(flippedCards));
  }
```

Y para aquellos curiosos que quieran ver la solución completa, aquí dejo el enlace de GitHub a mi [main.js](https://github.com/murguiRG/Portfolio/blob/main/Memory_game/js/main.js). Espero que esto sea de ayuda. ;)